# css match attributes with boolean logical

Tags: css, attributes

in css, to match multiple attributes you can use:

```
selector[attr1][attr2]{
    code goes here
}
```

is there any way to have css match attributes using boolean logic? for example:

```
selector[attr1]OR[attr2]{
    code goes here
}
```

would apply to any instance of that `selector` that has `attr1`, `attr2`, or both!

**does this exist? If so, what is the syntax?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
selector[attr1], selector[attr2]{
code goes here
}
```